# Phonegap ios app rejected due to app crash at launch

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-build

Our iOS app got rejected stating that the app got crashed at launch. However we never experienced the crash in any of our devices.

Phonegap version used - 3.5.0-0.21.14

Apple has attached 2 .crash files. In both the files the app got crashed in thread,  "Thread 5 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-qos"
after the thread, "Thread 12 name:  WebCore: LocalStorage" is executed.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Here is the part of the crash report from .crash file.

```
Thread 5 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-qos
Thread 5 Crashed:
0   libicucore.A.dylib              0x00000001967516dc 0x1965c8000 + 1611484
1   libicucore.A.dylib              0x00000001967516d0 0x1965c8000 + 1611472
2   Foundation                      0x000000018638a3dc 0x186320000 + 435164
3   Foundation                      0x0000000186389c38 0x186320000 + 433208
4   PAYBACK                         0x00000001000b28bc 0x10009c000 + 92348
5   PAYBACK                         0x00000001000b2974 0x10009c000 + 92532
6   PAYBACK                         0x00000001000ea2d4 0x10009c000 + 320212
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000197285990 0x197284000 + 6544
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000197285950 0x197284000 + 6480
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019729277c 0x197284000 + 59260
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000197293c48 0x197284000 + 64584
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197465228 0x197464000 + 4648
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib       

Thread 12 name:  WebCore: LocalStorage
Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001973cb078 0x1973b0000 + 110712
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197466f28 0x197464000 + 12072
2   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001869e97bc 0x1869d0000 + 104380
3   WebCore                         0x000000019466e32c 0x193a34000 + 12821292
4   WebCore                         0x0000000193be0ff8 0x193a34000 + 1757176
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001869e4b9c 0x1869d0000 + 84892
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197467dc4 0x197464000 + 15812
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197467d20 0x197464000 + 15648
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197464ef4 0x197464000 + 3828

Thread 5 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x000000015d51db40   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0xffffffffffffffe0   x3: 0x0000000101cef8a0
    x4: 0x0000000101cef900   x5: 0x0000000196710450   x6: 0x0000000101cefce8   x7: 0x0000000000000000
    x8: 0x4000000000000000   x9: 0x0000000000000006  x10: 0x0000000000000000  x11: 0x0000000000000000
   x12: 0x0000000000000592  x13: 0x0000000000000000  x14: 0x0000000000000000  x15: 0x0000000000000000
   x16: 0x000000019745d580  x17: 0x00000001853fdd64  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000101cefc08
   x20: 0x0000000170266fc0  x21: 0x0000000101cefa08  x22: 0x0000000000000000  x23: 0x0000000101cef850
   x24: 0x0000000101cef9fc  x25: 0x0000000000000000  x26: 0x000000018a77ff43  x27: 0x000000018a72d172
   x28: 0x0000000170057eb0  fp: 0x0000000101cef910   lr: 0x00000001967516d4
    sp: 0x0000000101cef850   pc: 0x00000001967516dc cpsr: 0x60000000
```

Comment: have u tested ur app in 64 bit device

Comment: Yes. both in iphone 6, ipad mini 2.

Comment: have you tryed to install the same version you submitted from itunes connect testflight?

Comment: Yes. Tried installing from test flight too. We did not encounter any issue. Tried many times starting the app.

Comment: @BharathVN did you ever resolve this?

Comment: @Carlos -  For us the issue was with the phonegap version(3.5.0-0.21.14). We  updated to version 5.1.1-0.29.0, and gave another build,  the app got accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For us the issue was with the phonegap version(3.5.0-0.21.14). We updated to version 5.1.1-0.29.0, and gave another build, the app got accepted.